# How to exclude transitive dependency in ant build using maven task for ant?

Tags: maven, ant, maven-ant-tasks

How to exclude transitive dependency in maven task for ant. Scope: runtime and provided doesn't seem to be of any help in this case.
This is my build.xml

```
<artifact:remoteRepository url="https://mynexus/" id="remote.repository"/>

<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
     <dependency version="1.7.0" artifactId="commons-beanutils" groupId="commons-beanutils"/>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

commons-beanutils has dependency commons-logging that I need to exclude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven-ant supports this exclusion, please RTFM
https://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/reference.html#exclusion

just as

```
<artifact:dependencies filesetId="dependency.fileset" useScope="runtime">
  <artifact:dependency version="1.7.0" artifactId="commons-beanutils" groupId="commons-beanutils">
    <exclusion groupId="commons-logging" artifactId="commons-logging">
  </<artifact:dependency>
</artifact:dependencies>
```

But I didn't find any supports for exclude some dependencies defined by a pom file

Comment: the link you reference states that the element name is exclusion not exclude (maybe that changed since you posted the link)

Comment: @cproinger thank you, I had just make a mistake, now the tag name is correctted

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Maven task supports this feature. Have you considered using Apache ivy instead? The following 2 examples demonstrates the exclusion capability.

The [cachepath](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/cachepath.html) task is useful for managing classpaths:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path">
  <dependency org="commons-beanutils" name="commons-beanutils" rev="1.7.0" conf="default">
    <exclude module="commons-logging"/>
  </dependency>
</ivy:cachepath>
```

The [retrieve](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/retrieve.html) task can be used to download and save files locally:

```
<ivy:retrieve pattern="lib/[artifact]-[revision](-[classifier]).[ext]">
  <dependency org="commons-beanutils" name="commons-beanutils" rev="1.7.0" conf="default">
    <exclude module="commons-logging"/>
  </dependency>
</ivy:retrieve>
```

Comment: I am trying to use maven-ant task

Comment: @user3199100 Understood. As stated, I'm not aware that the Maven ANT task supports your desired functionality.